# index.html working well, localhost:5000/ not showing background

Tags: python, html, css, debugging, http-status-code-404

index.html working well, localhost:5000/ not showing background, help!

i set the correct path to style.css and it works opened using index. But i do using server localhost:5000/ and it doesn't show any background. not sure what im doing wrong.

when i try to inspect from browser it say ERROR 404, style.css NOT FOUND
i just want to show the background animated like it seems in codepen.

```
Here is my code app.py:


# -------------------- Importaciones -------------------- #

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask import send_from_directory


# -------------------- App -------------------- #

app = Flask(__name__) # Creo la app.


# -------------------- ROUTES -------------------- #

@app.route('/') # Página principal, qué se llama index.
def start(): # Creo una función que me retorne con un return hacia la página.
    return render_template('website/index.html')

@app.route('/register') # Página de registro.
def register():
    return render_template('website/register.html')

@app.route('/loged') # Página para logearse.
def loged():
    return render_template('website/loged.html')

@app.route('/us') # Página de nosotros.
def us():
    return render_template('website/us.html')


if __name__ == '__main__': # Inicializamos nuestra app con el .run.
    app.run(debug = True)

-------------------------------

index.html code:

<!-- Importaciones y demás -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Título</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>


<!-- Comienza el código -->

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main">
            
        <!-- Menú cabecera -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="nav navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/register" aria-current="page">Registrarse</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/loged">Iniciar sesión</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">FREE</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/us">Nosotros</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
            
            <!-- Boton de Iniciar sesión -->

            <!--<button  class="pulse" onclick="window.location.href='http://Tibia.com';" >
                <b>Iniciar sesion</b>
            </button>-->
            
            <!-- Animación fondo -->
            
            <div class="d1"></div>
            <div class="d2"></div>
            <div class="d3"></div>
            <div class="d4"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>

style.css code:

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
  .main {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
  }
  .d1 {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(../image/Leesinbackground.png);
    background-size: 1920px 1080px;
  
    height: 30vh;
    width: 15vw;
  
    background-position: 0 50%;
  
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 2;
    animation: dd1 10s 1, dd12 10s 1;
    animation-delay: 4s, 14s;
  }
  .d2 {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(https://images4.alphacoders.com/817/817016.png);
    background-size: 1920px 1080px;
  
    height: 50vh;
    width: 25vw;
  
    background-position: -10vw 50%;
    left: 10vw;
  
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    animation: dd2 10s 2;
    animation-delay: 4s;
  }
  .d3 {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(https://images4.alphacoders.com/817/817016.png);
    background-size: 1920px 1080px;
    overflow: hidden;
  
    height: 100vh;
    width: 40vw;
    left: 25vw;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    background-position: -35vw 50%;
  
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 3;
    animation: dd3 10s 2;
    animation-delay: 4s;
  }
  .d4 {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(https://images4.alphacoders.com/817/817016.png);
    background-size: 1920px 1080px;
  
    height: 80vh;
    width: 25vw;
    left: 60vw;
    background-position: -70vw 50%;
  
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    animation: dd4 10s 2;
    animation-delay: 4s;
  }
  
  @keyframes dd1 {
    0% {
    }
    50% {
      width: 95vw;
    }
  }
  @keyframes dd12 {
    0% {
    }
    50% {
      background-position: Calc(0vw - 40px) 50%;
    }
  }
  @keyframes dd2 {
    0% {
    }
    50% {
      background-position: Calc(-10vw - 40px) 50%;
    }
  }
  @keyframes dd3 {
    0% {
    }
    50% {
      background-position: Calc(-35vw - 40px) 50%;
    }
  }
  @keyframes dd4 {
    0% {
    }
    50% {
      background-position: Calc(-70vw - 40px) 50%;
    }
  }


/*------------------------- Boton -------------------------*/

.pulse:hover,
.pulse:focus {
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1s;
          animation: pulse 1s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2em transparent;
  
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 var(--hover);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 var(--hover);
  }
}

.pulse {
  --color: #4f0909;
  --hover: #1b06a7;
}

button {
  color: var(--color);
  transition: 0.25s;
}
button:hover, button:focus {
  border-color: var(--hover);
  color: rgb(18, 0, 108);
}

body {
  font: 300 1em "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

code {
  color: #e4cb58;
  font: inherit;
}

/*------------------------- OTROS -------------------------*/
```

Comment: Your css is pathed to be page relative.  You probably don't want that. Secondly, I usually set up a static assets route to help handle routing to css and js and images.

Comment: @JonSG bro, im really trying to understand and searching everywhere to get the idea about "my css is pathed to be a page relative" im so confused. could you recommend a video?

Comment: Flask likely does not understand how to route `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />` as it is a relative path.  Try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />`.  You also likely in the future what to configure flask to understand how to serve `static_url_path`.  Check out https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/

Comment: @JonSG i had alredy tried it, and still not working but finally fix it, omg, using this: 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css' ) }}"/> and doing a folder named static. 
Omg dude this was so confused  for me. i got the correct way because you said it "static/relative page" Thanks mate.